# parameter unable to change through _ini.xml in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

my intention is to change a parameter of a component through the *_init.xml*:

The model is declared as:

```
model ModelA
  ...
  parameter Types.ActivePower PRefConst = 0
  ...
  Types.ActivePower PRef(nominal = SNom) =  PRefConst
   ...
end ModelA;
```

During the instantiation of `ModelA`, the `PRefConst` is assigned to a value:

```
  model_a ModelA(..., PRefConst = 14.9e6, ...);
```

In the compiled C code, it can be noticed that the `PRefConst`'s value is assigned hard-coded:

```
/*
equation index: 6068
type: SIMPLE_ASSIGN
model_a .PRefConst = 14900000.0
*/
void modelName_eqFunction_6068(DATA *data, threadData_t *threadData)
{
  TRACE_PUSH
  const int equationIndexes[2] = {1,6068};
  data->simulationInfo->realParameter[1565] /* model_a .PRefConst PARAM */ = 14900000.0;
  TRACE_POP
}

/*
equation index: 6067
type: SIMPLE_ASSIGN
model_a .PRef = model_a .PRefConst
*/
void modelName_eqFunction_6067(DATA *data, threadData_t *threadData)
{
  TRACE_PUSH
  const int equationIndexes[2] = {1,6067};
  data->simulationInfo->realParameter[1564] /* model_a .PRef PARAM */ = data->simulationInfo->realParameter[1565] /* model_a .PRefConst PARAM */;
  TRACE_POP
}
```

So that even I chang the value of `PRefConst` in the *_init.xml* file, in the end the simulation result shows that even though the `PRefConst` is correctly changed, however the value of `PRef` is still 14900000.0, because it is already assigned by the original PRefConst's value in the C code. How can I avoid this? Maybe through some options in **preOptModules** or **postOptModules**?
My current preOptModules is set to

```
setPreOptModules("normalInlineFunction,expandDerOperator,clockPartitioning,findStateOrder,inlineArrayEqn,encapsulateWhenConditions")
```

Comment: What OM version do you use? If you do instantiateModel and search for this component do you have a binding for it (directly on the variable definition), or an equation in an equation section?

Comment: Hi Adrian, sorry for my late reply. The OM version is 1.14, I solved this by a workaround using DAEMode, after enabling it the parameters aren't hard-coded anymore